# 3 users shown in who you'll work with in ad but only 2 show up in the company page

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs, advertising

Today I saw an add and 3 users were listed in the "who you'll work with" section.  What drew my eye was that I saw the same name listed twice.  The users have different avatars so I thought maybe it's just two people with the same name.  Alas when I went to the company page though the second listing for the users does not show up.  This is the add:

[image]

And this is the [company page](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/quikorder):

[image]

What is going on here?

Comment: Gregori's Gravatar isn't consistent either

Comment: We don't talk about Jim... the other Jim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup, that's definitely a bug. The Company Page ads are technically a separate app from the one that shows the Company Page, so there's a bit of code that synchronizes data between the two.

TL;DR: That code was missing a line that filters out profiles that are marked as "hidden" on the Company Page.

It's been fixed and should be deployed to the wild soon. Thanks for the tip!